# ionic leaflet angularjs directive - switching tileLayer in side menu thru Service

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-leaflet-directive

I am trying to test develop ionic app for leaflet-angularjs-directive. There's not many demos for me to try out.

I am using: ionic-leafletjs-map-demo by calendee (github) https://github.com/calendee/ionic-leafletjs-map-demo

And I am trying to reproduce the LocationsService to an another service: HistoricalMapService. Whenever I have added that HistoricalMapService, the webpage view for "ionic serve" is blank. When I commented it, the webpage is working but didn't use the HistoricalMapService.

Here's my code in the mapController.js (js/controller/mapController.js)

```
angular.module('starter').controller('MapController',
  [ '$scope',
    '$cordovaGeolocation',
    '$stateParams',
    '$ionicModal',
    '$ionicPopup',
    'LocationsService',
    /*'HistoricalMapService',*/
    'InstructionsService',
    function(
      $scope,
      $cordovaGeolocation,
      $stateParams,
      $ionicModal,
      $ionicPopup,
      LocationsService,
      /*HistoricalMapService,*/
      InstructionsService
      ) {

  /**
   * Once state loaded, get put map on scope.
   */
  $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {

    $scope.locations = LocationsService.savedLocations;
    $scope.newLocation;

    if(!InstructionsService.instructions.newLocations.seen) {

      var instructionsPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Add Locations',
        template: InstructionsService.instructions.newLocations.text
      });
      instructionsPopup.then(function(res) {
        InstructionsService.instructions.newLocations.seen = true;
        });

    }

    $scope.map = {
      defaults: {
        tileLayer: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/sla.c97ab90d/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2xhIiwiYSI6Ik15dE1uclUifQ.ZmSBZxWOZYCSW3m71abSzQ#17'
      },
      center: {
        lat: 1.355,
        lng: 103.840, 
        zoom: 14,
        minZoom: 12,
        maxZoom: 18,
        zoomControlPosition: 'topleft'
      },
      markers : {},
      events: {
        map: {
          enable: ['context'],
          logic: 'emit'
        }
      }
    };

    //$scope.goTo(0);
    $scope.locate();

  });

  var Location = function() {
    if ( !(this instanceof Location) ) return new Location();
    this.lat  = "";
    this.lng  = "";
    this.name = "";
  };

  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/addLocation.html', {
    scope: $scope,
    animation: 'slide-in-up'
  }).then(function(modal) {
      $scope.modal = modal;
    });

  /**
   * Detect user long-pressing on map to add new location
   */
  $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.contextmenu', function(event, locationEvent){
    $scope.newLocation = new Location();
    $scope.newLocation.lat = locationEvent.leafletEvent.latlng.lat;
    $scope.newLocation.lng = locationEvent.leafletEvent.latlng.lng;
    $scope.modal.show();
  });

  $scope.saveLocation = function() {
    LocationsService.savedLocations.push($scope.newLocation);
    $scope.modal.hide();
    $scope.goTo(LocationsService.savedLocations.length - 1);
  };

  /**
   * Center map on specific saved location
   * @param locationKey
   */
  $scope.goTo = function(locationKey) {

    var location = LocationsService.savedLocations[locationKey];

    $scope.map.center  = {
      lat : location.lat,
      lng : location.lng,
      zoom : 12
    };

    $scope.map.markers[locationKey] = {
      lat:location.lat,
      lng:location.lng,
      message: location.name,
      focus: true,
      draggable: false
    };

  };

  $scope.goToMapYear = function(histmap) {

    var histmap = HistoricalMapService.locateMapYear[histmap];

    console.log("Map Year: " + histmap.name);
    console.log("Map Layer: " + histmap.tileLayer);

    $scope.map = { 
      defaults: {
        tileLayer: histmap.tileLayer
        },
      center: {
        lat: 1.355,
        lng: 103.840, 
        zoom: 14,
        minZoom: 12,
        maxZoom: 18,
        zoomControlPosition: 'topleft'
      },
      markers : {},
      events: {
        map: {
          enable: ['context'],
          logic: 'emit'
        }
      }
    };

  };

  /**
   * Center map on user's current position
   */
  $scope.locate = function(){

    $cordovaGeolocation
      .getCurrentPosition()
      .then(function (position) {
        $scope.map.center.lat  = position.coords.latitude;
        $scope.map.center.lng = position.coords.longitude;
        $scope.map.center.zoom = 15;

        $scope.map.markers.now = {
          lat:position.coords.latitude,
          lng:position.coords.longitude,
          message: "You Are Here",
          focus: true,
          draggable: false
        };

      }, function(err) {
        // error
        console.log("Location error!");
        console.log(err);
      });

  };

}]);
```

And my historicalMapService (js/services/historicalMapService.js) in here: http://pastebin.com/mYsU0Dpk

And my menu.html (templates/menu.html) as follows:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive nav-title-slide-ios7">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear"><i class="icon ion-ios7-arrow-back"></i></ion-nav-back-button>

</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view name="menuContent" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>
```

```
<header class="bar bar-header bar-stable">
  <h1 class="title">Map Year</h1>
</header>

<ion-content class="has-header">

  <ion-list>

    <!--<ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="goTo(locationKey)" ng-repeat="(locationKey,location) in locations track by location.name">
      {{location.name}}
    </ion-item>-->

    <ion-item nav-clear menu-close ng-click="goToMapYear(histmap)" ng-repeat="(histmap,mapyear) in mapyears track by mapyear.name">
      {{mapyear.name}}
    </ion-item>

  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

How can I display the Layer's Name and when the user clicked on it, it will switch the map in the TMS TileLayer?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: I have solved this issue. Code is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Solved: Updated

mapController.js + using shared attributes

```
/*angular.module('starter').controller('MapController', ['$scope', 'leafletData',
    function($scope, leafletData) {
            leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
                L.GeoIP.centerMapOnPosition(map, 15);
            });
    }
]); */



angular.module('starter').controller('MapController',
  [ '$scope',
    '$cordovaGeolocation',
    '$stateParams',
    '$ionicModal',
    '$ionicPopup',
    '$http',
    'LocationsService',
    'InstructionsService',
    function(
      $scope,
      $cordovaGeolocation,
      $stateParams,
      $ionicModal,
      $ionicPopup,
      $http,
      LocationsService,
      InstructionsService
      ) {

      /**
       * Once state loaded, get put map on scope.
       */
      $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {

        $scope.locations = LocationsService.savedLocations;
        $scope.newLocation;

        if(!InstructionsService.instructions.newLocations.seen) {

          var instructionsPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Add Locations',
            template: InstructionsService.instructions.newLocations.text
          });
          instructionsPopup.then(function(res) {
            InstructionsService.instructions.newLocations.seen = true;
            });

        }

      $scope.basemapLayers = {
        basemap: {
          name: 'BaseMap',
          url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/sla.c97ab90d/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2xhIiwiYSI6Ik15dE1uclUifQ.ZmSBZxWOZYCSW3m71abSzQ#17',
          type: 'xyz'
        },
        map1955: {
          name: '1955',
          url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/sla.d62b6062/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2xhIiwiYSI6Ik15dE1uclUifQ.ZmSBZxWOZYCSW3m71abSzQ#17',
          type: 'xyz'
        },
        map1969: {
          name: '1969',
          url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/sla.d33a760d/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2xhIiwiYSI6Ik15dE1uclUifQ.ZmSBZxWOZYCSW3m71abSzQ#17',
          type: 'xyz'
        },
        map1975: {
          name: '1975',
          url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/sla.dbfef17c/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2xhIiwiYSI6Ik15dE1uclUifQ.ZmSBZxWOZYCSW3m71abSzQ#17',
          type: 'xyz'
        },
        map1988: {
          name: '1988',
          url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/sla.65929e4d/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2xhIiwiYSI6Ik15dE1uclUifQ.ZmSBZxWOZYCSW3m71abSzQ#17',
          type: 'xyz'
        },
        map1998: {
          name: '1998',
          url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/sla.d7a29a60/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2xhIiwiYSI6Ik15dE1uclUifQ.ZmSBZxWOZYCSW3m71abSzQ#17',
          type: 'xyz'
        },
        map2007: {
          name: '2007',
          url: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/sla.7ce67a24/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2xhIiwiYSI6Ik15dE1uclUifQ.ZmSBZxWOZYCSW3m71abSzQ#17',
          type: 'xyz'
        }
      }    

        $scope.map = {
          defaults: {
            //tileLayer: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/sla.c97ab90d/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2xhIiwiYSI6Ik15dE1uclUifQ.ZmSBZxWOZYCSW3m71abSzQ#17',
            //tileLayer: 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
              layers: {
                baselayers: {
              basemap: $scope.basemapLayers.basemap,              
              map2007: $scope.basemapLayers.map2007,
              map1998: $scope.basemapLayers.map1998,
              map1988: $scope.basemapLayers.map1988,
              map1975: $scope.basemapLayers.map1975,
              map1969: $scope.basemapLayers.map1969,
              map1955: $scope.basemapLayers.map1955
              }
            }            
          },
           center: {
            lat: 1.355,
            lng: 103.840, 
            zoom: 14,
            minZoom: 12,
            maxZoom: 18,
            zoomControlPosition: 'topleft'
                },
          markers : {},
          events: {
            map: {
              enable: ['context'],
              logic: 'emit'
            }
          }
        };

        //$scope.goTo(0);
        $scope.locate();

        //$scope.map2 = $scope.map;

        $scope.map2 = {
          defaults: {
            //tileLayer: 'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/sla.c97ab90d/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoic2xhIiwiYSI6Ik15dE1uclUifQ.ZmSBZxWOZYCSW3m71abSzQ#17',
            //tileLayer: 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
              layers: {
                baselayers: {
              map1955: $scope.basemapLayers.map1955,
              map1969: $scope.basemapLayers.map1969,
              map1975: $scope.basemapLayers.map1975,
              map1988: $scope.basemapLayers.map1988,
              map1998: $scope.basemapLayers.map1998,
              map2007: $scope.basemapLayers.map2007,
              basemap: $scope.basemapLayers.basemap
              }
            }            
          },
           center: {
            lat: 1.355,
            lng: 103.840, 
            zoom: 14,
            minZoom: 12,
            maxZoom: 18,
            zoomControlPosition: 'topleft'
                },
          markers : {},
          events: {
            map: {
              enable: ['context'],
              logic: 'emit'
            }
          }
        };

        //$scope.goTo(0);
        $scope.locate();

      });

      var Location = function() {
        if ( !(this instanceof Location) ) return new Location();
        this.lat  = "";
        this.lng  = "";
        this.name = "";
      };

      $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/addLocation.html', {
        scope: $scope,
        animation: 'slide-in-up'
      }).then(function(modal) {
          $scope.modal = modal;
        });

      /**
       * Detect user long-pressing on map to add new location
       */
      $scope.$on('leafletDirectiveMap.contextmenu', function(event, locationEvent){
        $scope.newLocation = new Location();
        $scope.newLocation.lat = locationEvent.leafletEvent.latlng.lat;
        $scope.newLocation.lng = locationEvent.leafletEvent.latlng.lng;
        $scope.modal.show();
      });

      $scope.saveLocation = function() {
        LocationsService.savedLocations.push($scope.newLocation);
        $scope.modal.hide();
        $scope.goTo(LocationsService.savedLocations.length - 1);
      };

      /**
       * Center map on specific saved location
       * @param locationKey
       */
      $scope.goTo = function(locationKey) {

        var location = LocationsService.savedLocations[locationKey];

        $scope.map.center  = {
          lat : location.lat,
          lng : location.lng,
          zoom : 14
        };

        $scope.map.markers[locationKey] = {
          lat:location.lat,
          lng:location.lng,
          message: location.name,
          focus: true,
          draggable: false
        };

      };

      $scope.goToMapYear = function(histmap) {

        var mapyear = HistoricalMapService.locateMapYear[histmap];

      };

      /**
       * Center map on user's current position
       */
      $scope.locate = function(){

        $cordovaGeolocation
          .getCurrentPosition()
          .then(function (position) {
            $scope.map.center.lat  = position.coords.latitude;
            $scope.map.center.lng = position.coords.longitude;
            $scope.map.center.zoom = 15;

            $scope.map.markers.now = {
              lat:position.coords.latitude,
              lng:position.coords.longitude,
              message: "You Are Here",
              focus: true,
              draggable: false
            };

          }, function(err) {
            // error
            console.log("Location error!");
            console.log(err);
          });

      };

    }]);
```

map.html (not using menu.html)

```
<ion-view title="OneMap">

  <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
    <button menu-toggle="left" class="button button-icon icon ion-navicon"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button ng-click="locate();" title="Search" class="button button-icon icon ion-ios-search-strong"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>

<div class="row">

    <ion-content data-tap-disabled="true" class="col col-50">

        <leaflet id="map1" event-broadcast="map.defaults.events" defaults="map.defaults" center="map.center" markers="map.markers" layers="map.defaults.layers" width="100%" height="100%" ng-if="map"></leaflet>

    </ion-content>

    <ion-content data-tap-disabled="true" class="col col-50" style="left: 50%;">

        <leaflet id="map2" event-broadcast="map.defaults.events" defaults="map.defaults" center="map.center" markers="map.markers" layers="map2.defaults.layers" width="100%" height="100%" ng-if="map2"></leaflet>

    </ion-content>

</div>

  <ion-tabs id="actionTabs" class="tabs-positive tabs-icon-top">

    <a ng-click="locate();" name="Find Me" class="button button-icon icon ion-pinpoint" style="color: white;"></button>

</ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>

</ion-view>
```